# Вызывать функцию на смене слайда slick.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Мне нужно запускать js функцию по смене слайда в slick.js.

Я использую slick + jquery на своем сайте. Есть ли способ при смене слайда вызвать функцию.

Пример кода того что мне нужно:

```
slick.changeSlide(function(){
   doSometing();
});
```

Comment: у вас есть возможность вызывать обработки событий перед сменой слайда, и после